# Revealing an item in an array of hidden text to the corresponding button from an array of buttons

Tags: javascript

So for my website, I read data from a database, each video game has a description, once I receive the description from the database using PHP, I split the description into 2 parts one part that is visible and another that is hidden until the user clicks "Read More". I have multiple games on a page which means I have multiple "Read Me" buttons. In my javascript, I have the code so when the user clicks any of the "read me" buttons that the selected button disappears.

This is the part that I have my issue, how do I get it so when the user clicks one of the "Read me" buttons that the hidden text that corresponds with that button is displayed?

Here is the code I have right now.

```
var readMoresList = document.getElementsByClassName("readMore");
for (var i = 0; i < readMoresList.length; i++) {
  readMoresList[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var selected = e.target;
  selected.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  //here i am selecting the second description that is hidden
  var reveals = document.getElementsByClassName("readMore");
  reveals[i].style.visibility = 'visible';

}); }
```

so The readMoreList variable is the array of readMore buttons, I get them and add an eventListener to them and wait till they are clicked.
The reveals variable is the array of hidden descriptions.

What I am looking for is how to set things up so when I click on a readMe button the hidden text that is adjacent to that read me will be visible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
  //here i am selecting the second description that is hidden
  var reveals = document.getElementsByClassName("readMore");
```

No, you're selecting the buttons again. Use a different class for the hidden text.

```
  reveals[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
```

By the time this runs, `i` will always be equal to `readMoresList.length`. [Closures inside loops can be counter-intuitive.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/9029328)

Comment: yes, my apologies I was playing around with my code before I posted it. Even with the change I still have the same problem. I need to find a way to reveal the text that corresponds to the "read me" button that is selected. So ill basically have 2 arrays 1 filled with the buttons with the "click" eventListner and an array filled with hidden texts for each game. I need to find a way to say when "readMe" is clicked, hide the "read me" button and make the text for that game visible

Comment: @CodingJedi Did you read the linked question? That's the crux of the problem. Applying one of the solutions there to your code will fix it.

Comment: Thank you, my apologies again, on my screen it looked like normal text. Thanks for the help that solved the problem